# Redux - Trying to add a function to configureStore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to persist my redux to localStorage, but I don't know how to add it to redux-toolkit's configureStore function.

### Error:

> Argument of type '{ reducer: { progress: Reducer; }; persistedState: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConfigureStoreOptions<{ progress: number; }, AnyAction>'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'persistedState' does not exist in type 'ConfigureStoreOptions<{ progress: number; }, AnyAction>'.

### Code:

**localStorage.ts**

```
export const loadState = () => {
  try {
    const serializedState = localStorage.getItem("state");
    if (serializedState === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch (err) {
    return undefined;
  }
};
```

**index.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import counterSlice from "./store/reducers/counterSlice";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
// import throttle from "lodash.throttle";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { loadState, saveState } from "./store/localStorage";

const reducer = {
  progress: counterSlice
};
const persistedState = loadState();
const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
  persistedState
});

store.subscribe(() => {
  saveState({
    progress: store.getState().progress
  });
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm the creator of Redux Toolkit.  `persistedState` is not a valid configuration option for `configureStore`.  [The correct field name is `preloadedState`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#preloadedstate).

Comment: I have another question. If I use a third party middleware, like redux-localstorage-simple, how do I pass that into configureStore? It doesn't work with an array of elements.

Comment: `configureStore` specifically accepts [an argument called `middleware`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#middleware), which is an array of middleware instances.

Comment: I tried that, but it didnt work with typescript error message:                                        Type '(((options?: RLSOptions | undefined) => Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch<AnyAction>>) | ((options?: LoadOptions | undefined) => object))[]' is not assignable to type 'Middleware<{}, { signupWizard: { surveyAnswers: {}; }; }, Dispatch<AnyAction>>[]'.

Comment: That looks like you're not actually creating your middleware instance - you're passing in a function that _returns_ a middleware instance. But,I can't say for sure without actually seeing your complete code.

Comment: ```const store = configureStore({
  reducer
  middleware: [save(), load()]
});
```                                                                                                                                 This is all that I'm doing. I'm using redux-localstorage-simple.

Comment: Based on those API docs, `load` is actually a function that returns the preloaded state, not a middleware.  Try: `configureStore({reducer, preloadedState: load(), middleware: [save(), ...getDefaultMiddleware()] })`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using configureStore use createStore. 
For me this works:

```
const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    persistedState
  );
```

full example:

```
  const loadFromLocalStorage = () => {
    try {
      const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
      return JSON.parse(serializedState);
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e)
    }
  };

  const saveToLocalStorage = state => {
    try {
      const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
      localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e)
    }
  };

  const state= loadFromLocalStorage();


  const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    state
  );
  store.subscribe(() => {
    saveToLocalStorage(store.getState());
  });
```

Comment: now it gives the same error, but on the reducer side

Comment: I updated with full example. Can you try out? For me this works